# How can I get a scheduled notification that repeats every day in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, flutter-dependencies, android-notifications

I am using the **flutter_local_notifications** package and attempting to implement a notification system where I receive notifications daily at various times.

For example, one day I might receive a notification at 6:00 AM, the next day at 7:00 PM, and the following day at either 8:30 AM or 4:00 PM. However, notifications will occur daily.

I've tried utilizing both periodic notifications and scheduled notifications from **flutter_local_notifications**, but I'm struggling to understand how to achieve this.

This is my Notification Code

```
class LocalNotifications {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final onClickNotification = BehaviorSubject<String>();


  static void onNotificationTap(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    onClickNotification.add(notificationResponse.payload!);
  }


  static Future init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) => null,
    );
    final LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux =
        LinuxInitializationSettings(defaultActionName: 'Open notification');
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
            linux: initializationSettingsLinux);
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onNotificationTap,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onNotificationTap);
  }
  static Future showPeriodicNotifications({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('channel 2', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      1,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: payload,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
    );
  }


  static Future showScheduleNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String primeTimes,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    tz.TZDateTime payloadDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.parse(tz.local, primeTimes);

  
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        payloadDateTime,
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel 3',
          'your channel name',
          channelDescription: 'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          ticker: 'ticker',
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
        )),
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
        
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        payload: payload, 
        
        );
  }

}
```

Comment: So, you do not receive any scheduled notifications?

Comment: I receive scheduled notifications. But I want it daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter in zonedSchedule with a value, to get scheduled notification daily at the given time.

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
```

According to the package, it states that

> If a value for matchDateTimeComponents parameter is given, this tells
> the plugin to schedule a recurring notification that matches the
> specified date and time components. Specifying DateTimeComponents.time
> would result in a daily notification at the same time whilst
> DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime would result in a weekly
> notification that occurs on the same day of the week and time. This is
> similar to how recurring notifications on iOS/macOS work using a
> calendar trigger. Note that when a value is given, the scheduledDate
> may not represent the first time the notification will be shown. An
> example would be if the date and time is currently 2020-10-19 11:00
> (i.e. 19th October 2020 11:00AM) and scheduledDate is 2020-10-21 10:00
> and the value of the matchDateTimeComponents is
> DateTimeComponents.time, then the next time a notification will appear
> is 2020-10-20 10:00.